# Eclipse Indigo vs Helios - starting the app

Tags: eclipse

While in Eclipse Helios I could press the Debug or Run btn while editing any file, in particular also xml-files.

Now with Indigo I have to position the cursor in a Java-file and the press debug/run.

This is rather annoying when editing just some xml-files having to jump to a Java-file before able to run the app.

Is this a new "Feature" or is it possible to get the same behaviour as before?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature, called Context launching.  You can turn it off at the bottom of `Preferences>Run/Debug>Launching`.  See http://eclipse-debug.blogspot.ca/2007/05/context-launchingfriend-or-foe.html for more details.

Comment: sorry, I do not know what to change there - tried couple of settings but none helped. By the way the msg I get when being in an xml and trying to start the app is: "The JRE Instance Default XLST processor does not support debugging. Would you like to debug ..." - whoever understands this please help